# Custom Event Handling in COM c++

Tags: c++, event-handling, custom-event

I have a c#.NET class having an Event signature which  is exposed to COM using an outgoing interface like this::

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IHehServerEvents
    {
       string EmptyEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs args);
    }
```

In PluginAPI.h>>
I have

```
class PluginAPI: public IHehServerEvents,public FB::JSAPIAuto//implemented the COM outgoing interface
{
```

//declared EmptyEvent method based upon tlh file

```
 HRESULT __stdcall EmptyEvent(VARIANT sender,IUnknown * args, BSTR * pRetVal);
        FB_JSAPI_EVENT(CSharpEvent, 2, (FB::variant,IUnknown *));

    }
    HRESULT ClassCpluss::EmptyEvent(BSTR message, BSTR * pRetVal)
    {....}
```

My Event helper in Firebreath statement is

```
FB_JSAPI_EVENT(CSharpEvent, 2, (VARIANT,struct _EventArgs *));
```

I also saw [**THIS link**](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Supported+JSAPI+types). SO boost::vairant is supported right?Then how to cast VARIANT to boost::variant?
Any changes expected in the above statement?
How to handle the above event in c# by use of VARIANT or struct?any examples would be helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, boost::variant is not supported, FB::variant is supported -- it is not the same thing at all.  FB::variant is actually using boost::any internally.

What you're trying to do is mix COM and FireBreath and it's not going to have a good result.  Instead, create a class that talks to your COM stuff and use that from your JSAPI object.  Handle the event in your object and have it call a functor (look at boost::bind and boost::function) or maybe use signals and sockets from boost. There are lots of ways you can handle it, but the key here is that you need to first get your C++ object that knows how to talk to COM and then using that object from FireBreath will be easy.  Directly using a VARIANT or arbitrary struct type with firebreath events will never work.

Comment: Surely knew about boost::function and boost::bind.But can you give us a link/provide an example(of handling COM events in c++) and as to what you're talking about this statement "have it call a functor (look at boost::bind and boost::function) "

Comment: I haven't done any handling of COM events in c++.  To see an example of using a functor, look at the SimpleStreamsHelper class in the FireBreath codebase -- it uses a boost::function callback.  To see it used, look at FBTestPlugin where it uses SimpleStreamsHelper.